# Prototype defined as functions vs as an object

Tags: javascript

Are there any differences between the following two approaches to adding methods to a prototype?

```js
{
    let f = function(){};
    f.prototype.toString = function() { return "f()" }
    f.prototype.sayHi    = function(name) {console.log(`Hi, ${name}`);}
    console.log((new f()) + "");
}

{
    let f = function(){};
    f.prototype = {
        toString() { return "f()" },
        sayHi(name){console.log(`Hi, ${name}`)}
    }
    console.log((new f()) + "");
}
```

I've always seen the methods defined in the first way but I'm guessing they're the same thing?

Comment: The first adds to the prototype, the latter replaces it.

Comment: And modern JavaScript, just use a class.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences of the two ways of adding a prototype.

---

The **first example** *adds* some methods to the `prototype` of `f`. This is because you are setting keys to some functions.

As `prototype` is an object, we can also try the same thing with an object.

Let's set an empty object, and add a method and a value, as so.

```js
const obj = {};

obj.website = "stackoverflow.com";
obj.visit = () => {
  console.log(`Visit ${obj.website} today!`);
};
```

<sup>Note: Arrow syntax (`() => {}`) is new syntax, and isn't supported in legacy browsers.</sup>

You can see the similarities of an object and `prototype`.

---

The **second example** *overwrites* the entire `prototype` of `f`, as you are setting `prototype` to be an empty object, then containing some values.

You can see what is happening step-by-step with an object.

1. First, you define an object, and add a property of `name`, as so.

   ```js
   let obj = {};
   obj.name = "Stack Overflow";
   ```
2. Next, we'll add a URL to *Stack Overflow*, as so.

   ```js
   obj = {
     url: "stackoverflow.com",
   };
   ```
3. However, when we try to access the `.name` property, we get a value of `undefined`, as so.

   ```js
   console.log(`See ${obj.name} at ${obj.url}!`);
   // Outputs: See undefined at stackoverflow.com!
   ```

Here is the final result:

```js
// Step 1
let obj = {};
obj.name = "Stack Overflow";

// Step 2
obj = {
  url: "stackoverflow.com",
};

// Step 3
console.log(`See ${obj.name} at ${obj.url}!`);
```

This is the reason why `const` is used in objects; so that this issue doesn't occur!

---

In **summary**, there are differences between the two methods of changing prototypes.

1. The first example will add methods to the `prototype`, without deleting or overwriting the existing ones.
2. The second example will overwrite the existing methods in `prototype`, and add the new ones.

---

---

Also, just a side tip, in modern JavaScript, you should use a `class` instead of a `function` for prototypes like these. For example:

```js
class F {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  static toStr() {
    return "new F()";
  }
  
  sayHi() {
    console.log(`Hi ${this.name}!`);
    return this;
  }
}

console.log(F.toStr());

const f = new F("Person");
f.sayHi();
```

Here are some key points of what is happening:

- `class F` creates a new class called `F`. It is convention to use [`PascalCase`](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase) when naming a class.
- `constructor` is a special function which is called when the `new` keywork is used on `F`. It initialises the class. The parameters of `constructor` are  what you pass in when you initialise the class. Inside, you can add the parameter passed into `constructor` into `this` (special keyword), which makes it usable throughout the class. See [`constructor` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) for more information.
- The first method has the `static` keyword, which means it can be used without initialising the class. So, you don't need to use the `new` keyword to access it, but just do `ClassName.methodName()`. See [`static` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) for more information.
- The second function needs `F()` to be initialised with the `new` keyword before it can be used. It also returns `this` in the function body. This creates something called *method chaining*, which makes it possible to call another method or property after the method has been called.
- `F.toStr()` is calling the `toStr()` method on the class `F`. The reason you don't need to use the `new` keyword is because it was defined as a `static` method.
- The `new F()` part is creating a new instance of `F()`. Then, we are accessing a method off of it.

Comment: Noting that `const` isn't relevant to the OP's example--what's being replaced is a property *of* an object (`prototype`), not the variable that references the object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert at OOP but the second approach actually wipes out the previously defined prototypes.

```js
let f = function() {};

f.prototype.hello = function() {
      console.log("hello")
}

f.prototype.hello() // hello

f.prototype = {
      sayHi(name) {
        console.log(`Hi, ${name}`)
      }
}

f.prototype.hello() // throws TypeError
```